# maximum area of inscribed quadrilateral

Tags: area, quadrilateral

Find the maximum area of the quadrilateral inscribed on $y=2x-x^2$, where $y\geq 0$ and explain your answer.

I can just estimate the shape but I don't know how to prove it precisely. Help me with a explanation please.

Comment: Show us what you've done.  Otherwise, how can we explain why it's right?

Comment: What kind of quadrilateral is it? Arbitrary or some special?

Comment: It is arbitrary. Thank you for asking.

Comment: I proved with expressions that two points of the rectangle must be placed where the graph meets with x-axis. Also we can explain with specifying rectangle's point with proof and explanation.

Comment: You could find the area under the curve between x=0 and x=2 by integration. This area will be the upper bound of the inscribed shape of which has an area described by the formula https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-area-quadrilateral/ or here:https://www.mathopenref.com/quadrilateralinscribedarea.html also max are is shown here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral#Maximum_and_minimum_properties

Comment: Considering one side should lie on axis $x$, you need to pick two points on axis $x$ and two points on parabola. Also, break quadrilateral into two triangles,

Comment: Thanks for replying and I will try again.

Answer (score 2):

For arbitrary quadrilateral, obviously, the two vertices should lie at $(0,0)$ and $(2,0)$ and the other two should lie on different sides of $(1,0)$. Refer to the figure:

[image]

Let the two vertices be $A(a,2a-a^2)$ and $B(b,2b-b^2)$. Note the quadrilateral is not necessarily an isosceles trapezium (although it will be at the end). Find the area of the quadrilateral (which is the sum of the areas of two triangles on the sides and trapezium in the middle):
$$S=\frac12\cdot a\cdot (2a-a^2)+\frac12\cdot (2a-a^2+2b-b^2)(b-a)+\frac12\cdot (2-b)(2b-b^2)=\\
-\frac12a^2b+\frac12ab^2-b^2+2b,0<a<1<b<2$$
Now maximize $S$:
$$\begin{cases}S_a=-ab+\frac12b^2=0\\
S_b=-\frac12a^2+ab-2b+2=0\end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{cases}a=\frac23\\ b=\frac43\end{cases}$$
I will leave checking the Hessian for you.
Hence, $S(\frac23,\frac43)=\frac{32}{27}$ is maximum area.

Note that the equations of red, green, blue lines are: $y=\frac43x,y=\frac89,y=-\frac43x+\frac83$, respectively. So, the quadrilateral is an isosceles trapezium.